# Identify columns with varying values for each set of columns

Tags: sql, distinct-values

Given a table, *t*:

```
a     b    c     d      e
1     2    3      4     7   
1     2    3      5     7
3     2    4      6     7
3     2    4      6     8
```

What SQL query can identify the columns that has one or more instances of varying values associated with each tuple from columns *a* and *b*, ?

In table *t* above, columns *d* and *e* would satisfy this criterion but not column *c*.

For tuples <1,2> and <3,2> that come from columns *a* and *b*, column *c* doesn't have varying values for each tuple.

Column *d* has one instance of varying values for tuple <1,2> -- values 4 and 5.

Column *e* also has one instance of varying values for tuple <3,2> -- values 7 and 8.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work for you using `CASE`, `COUNT` and `GROUP BY`:

```
select 
  a, b,
  case when count(distinct c) > 1 then 'yes' else 'no' end colc,
  case when count(distinct d) > 1 then 'yes' else 'no' end cold,
  case when count(distinct e) > 1 then 'yes' else 'no' end cole
from t
group by a, b
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4ce23/1)

Answer (score 0):

Slightly indirectly:

```
SELECT a, b,
       COUNT(DISTINCT c) AS num_c,
       COUNT(DISTINCT d) AS num_d,
       COUNT(DISTINCT e) AS num_e
  FROM t
 GROUP BY a, b;
```

This yields:

```
1   2   1   2   1
3   2   1   1   2
```

If the `num_c` or `num_d` or `num_e` column has a value greater than 1, then there are varying values.  You can vary the query to list whether the column is varying for a given value of (a, b) by using a CASE statement like this:

```
-- v for varying, n for non-varying
SELECT a, b,
       CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT C) > 1 THEN 'v' ELSE 'n' END AS num_c,
       CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT d) > 1 THEN 'v' ELSE 'n' END AS num_d,
       CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT e) > 1 THEN 'v' ELSE 'n' END AS num_e
  FROM t
 GROUP BY a, b;
```

This yields:

```
1   2   n   v   n
3   2   n   n   v
```

If you really want just to know whether any set of values in the given column varies for any values of (a, b) — and not which values of (a, b) it varies for — you can use the query above as a sub-query in the FROM clause and organize things as you want.

```
SELECT MAX(num_c) AS num_c,
       MAX(num_d) AS num_d,
       MAX(num_e) AS num_e
  FROM (SELECT a, b,
               CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT C) > 1 THEN 'v' ELSE 'n' END AS num_c,
               CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT d) > 1 THEN 'v' ELSE 'n' END AS num_d,
               CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT e) > 1 THEN 'v' ELSE 'n' END AS num_e
          FROM t
         GROUP BY a, b
       );
```

This relies on `v` being larger than `n`; it is easy enough (and convenient enough) for this binary decision, but not necessarily convenient or easy if there are, say, 4 states to map.

This yields:

```
n   v   v
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The last query is what I needed.